# ANTLR 3, what does LT!* mean?

Tags: grammar, antlr3

I was looking at the code for a Javascript grammar written in ANTLR 3,

http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/1206736738015/JavaScript.g

In many instances I found

```
program
    : LT!* sourceElements LT!* EOF!
    ;
```

what does `LT!*` mean ?

EDIT:

From 
http://ftp.camk.edu.pl/camk/chris/antlrman/antlrman.pdf

I found that `LT` stands for `LOOKAHEAD TOKEN` but it is the `N`th look ahead token, where is the `N` part in the above ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `LT` does not mean `LOOKAHEAD TOKEN` in this context. It is a token defined nearly at the end of the grammar:

```
LT
 : '\n'      // Line feed.
 | '\r'      // Carriage return.
 | '\u2028'  // Line separator.
 | '\u2029'  // Paragraph separator.
 ;
```

The `*` means that the parser tries to match zero or more of these tokens, and the `!` indicates that the generated AST should not include these `LT` tokens.

Comment: What is the point of writing like `LT!*` when It is already on the hidden channel ?

Comment: @mataug, if it really was on the hidden-channel, it could be removed completely from every parser rule. However, it is *not* placed on the hidden channel in the grammar.