# Why does antlr4 choke on LT!*

Tags: javascript, regex, antlr

I'm trying to use a JavaScript grammar with antlr4 (copyright 2008 by Chris Lambrou, retrieved from http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/1206736738015/JavaScript.g).  The script contains many instances of "LT!*", which I understand as a regex expression meaning zero or more line terminators and don't include the tokens in the generated AST (from answer to stackoverflow question [ANTLR 3, what does LT!* mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213085/antlr-3-what-does-lt-mean)).

antlr4 throws a syntax error for each instance of "LT!*" so I assume the most recent version doesn't handle that construct.  What can be used to replace "LT!*" that will work in antlr4?

[edit] Note that the syntax error is on the "!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANTLR 4 does not produce AST. Therefore, the `!` (and `->`) inside parser rules is not allowed.

See: [How can I build an AST using ANTLR4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823333/how-can-i-build-an-ast-using-antlr4)

Comment: Thanks.  I did a bit of looking around and couldn't quite find the answer - I was avoiding diving into the real documentation, but that appears to be the best way to go - had hoped antlr would be more of a wysiwyg tool, but after some more investigation I think it will be a worthwhile investment.  There goes another weekend ... and hopefully not another "25 years".  -Carl